# Does a general applicable transitive relation exist between test statistics and p-values?

Tags: distributions, variance, p-value, stochastic-ordering

For a proof I showed that, if a p-value has a uniform distribution between 0 and 1, then transforming these p-values back using the inverse of standard normal results in a random variable with variance 1.

Now, I wanted to show that the variance decreases if any stochastically larger p-values are drawn. But I am not sure if that is a general statement or only applicable for one-sided p-values.

Comment: This doesn't sound even remotely plausible, so I must not fully understand what you are describing.  Could you explain the alternative procedure in more detail?

Comment: So, to answer your question and with a look at the answer of John, which I appreciate, let us assume we have an exact test that gives us continuous p-values. Then, under the null hypothesis, the p values are uniformly distributed between 0 and1. If these p-values are transformed using the inverse quantile function of the standard normal distribution, the variance of these are 1.   
Now assuming I have a conservative test. The p-values from this test are stochastically larger compared to the p-values of the exact test. If those p-values are transformed, how does the variance then behave?

Comment: Unfortunately, this transformation often isn't even defined.  In many practical cases there is a positive chance the p-value will be exactly $1.$  This does guide the intuition, though, so I would invite you to contemplate a situation in which there is a 50% chance the p-value will be uniformly distributed on $[0,0.5]$ and a 50% chance it will be uniformly distributed on an interval $[1-\epsilon,1)$ extremely close to $1.$ Half the transformed values are negative and the other half of the transformed values can be made as large as you like: what happens to the variance?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it really helped me out there. I thought like John that the intuition, that a monotone relationship exists after the transformation of p-values. But using your simulation example showed me, that the relationship is not so simple, and stochastically larger p-values can be generated with variances greater than 1 after transformation. Therefore, the answer to my above question is no.